# How can I disable user input on mac console app C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to develop a console application for macOs that displays characters with a small delay in between each character, like if someone was typing the lines in the console.

I want to disable the user input while the message is being typed, but I can't figure out how to do it:

```
static void WriteToConsoleWithDelay(string msg, int delay = 75)
    {
        var e = msg.GetEnumerator();

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            var c = e.Current;
            Console.Write(c.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(totalDelay);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `Console.ReadKey(true)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I'm not sure it that solves it though... it interrupts execution, so I cannot keep writing to the console after I call it.